# Other causes for DirectShow "no combination of intermediate filters could be found" errors?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, pcm, dspack

I have a Delphi 6 application that uses the DSPACK DirectShow component library.  Currently I am getting the error "no combination of intermediate filters could be found" when I attempt to connect the Capture pin on an audio capture device to the Input pin of another filter.  I *believe* I am setting the media formats correctly.  I have an error trap and in that trap I query explicitly both pins for the exact media format they are set to in case there is an incongruity.  When I do this, both pins come back with the exact same WAV format:

format tag: 1

number of channels: 1

bits per sample: 16

sample rate: 8000

That matches up to what I set both filters to, yet I am getting an error that (usually as far as I know) indicates a format incompatibility.  Has anyone run into this error before and knows what I might be doing wrong or what other kinds of tests/inspections I can do?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error was being caused by the media format I was returning from my push source audio filter.  I had the wrong sub-type and that was triggering the "no combination of intermediate filters could be found" error from DirectShow since the sub-type I was using in my push source filter was incorrect and not compatible with other filters like the Capture filter I was using in my filter graph.  See the "UPDATE" note in my thread on media format's for full details:

[Correct Media Type settings for a DirectShow filter that delivers Wav audio data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909947/correct-media-type-settings-for-a-directshow-filter-that-delivers-wav-audio-data)